# How to pass an inherited class with nontype template to it's parent reference in C++

Tags: c++, class, sorting, inheritance

Consider the following code: collection technically is a vector with sort method in addition.

```
template<class T>
class collection
{
public:
  std::vector<T> vec;
  void sort(sortType& U, bool compare(T, T))
  {
      U.doSort(vec, compare) ;
  } 
}
```

And this is class sortType

```
template<class T>
class sortType
{
 protected:
   doSort(std::vector<T>&,  bool compare(T, T));
}
```

The following code is some different sorting methods that I want to use

```
template<class T>
class insertionsort : public sortType
{
 public: 
   doSort(std::vector<T>&, bool compare(T, T))
    {
      //code of insertion sort
    } 
} 

template<class T>
class quicksort : public sortType
{
 public: 
   doSort(std::vector<T>&, bool compare(T, T))
    {
      //code of quicksort
    } 
}
```

compare is a function look like this:

```
template <class T>
bool greater( T l, T r) 
{
    if (l<r) return true;
    return false;
}
```

I want to use the previous class like this:

```
insertionsort U = insertionsort() ;
collectionObj.sort(U, greater) ;
```

Unfortunately, visual studio announced that I cannot pass the insertionsort class to sortType class. How could I fix it and use something like those previous. 
Thank for helpings

Comment: `greater` has return type `bool`, but you return expressions of type `T`?

Comment: No greater just a compare condition to whether I will swap two elements or not

Comment: `insertionsort` is not a class. It's a template. `insertionsort U = insertionsort()` makes no sense. You need `insertionsort<something>`.  Ditto `sortType`. Ditto `greater`. `doSort` shoud be virtual.

Comment: Thank #n.m did I miss any thing else?

Comment: Yes, as the other commenter said you don't understand what `greater` should do.

Comment: I have corrected the code into what you said collectionObj.sort(new insertionsort<int>(), greater) but the compiler still anouces many errors. "insertionSort<int>* is not compatiple with sortType<int>*"

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
void sort(sortType& U, bool compare(T, T))
```

you are trying to pass `sortType`, but it is a template; actual type is `sortType<T>`, so function signature should be

```
void sort(sortType<T>& U, bool compare(T, T))
```

also, what **n.m.** mentioned in comments